# Django - Template displays edited user context info despite ValidationError

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Hi I'm working on a form to edit a user's profile. It properly updates the fields upon successful submission without any validation errors. The problem I'm having is that if the form does return a validation error upon submission and I've changed the name on the form, the template will display this new name instead of the old name. I'm assuming this is because it uses the user context provided by the POST request. Is there any way to properly display the user's old name until the form is actually successfully submitted? Below is my code.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.forms import ModelForm

class UserProfileForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="First Name", required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="Last Name", required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email", required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "username", "password1", "password2")

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError('This email is already in use.')
        return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class EditProfileForm(ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="First Name", required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="Last Name", required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email", required=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="New Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Repeat New Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "username", "password1", "password2")

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError('This email is already in use.')
        return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(EditProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('/overview')
    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('/overview')
        else:
            form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request, "/register.html", {'form': form})

@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/profile')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm()

    return render(request, '/edit_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

navbar.html

```
<li class="">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <img src="/ui/assets/images/user.png" alt="">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}
      <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu pull-right">
      <li><a href="/profile/"> Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="/logout/"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch a separate instance of the user from the db to use with the form. This way, the `request.user` will not be modified when the form is validated.

```
user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user)
```